# What adjective is used to describe something that's used, but that's not intended to be used in a particular way or for a particular purpose?

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a word that describes something, like a tool or any object that can be used to do something, in a way that's not intended or optimal. For example, using a dictionary to hammer down a nail.

For example:

> The Frostbite engine was used to make a RPG, because it was ___ it led
>   to several problems during the development cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most appropriate is [**misuse**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misuse):

> **1** : to use incorrectly : MISAPPLY
>   // *misused* his talents
>   // a word that is frequently *misused*

In your sentence:

> The Frostbite engine was used to make an RPG; because it was *misused* it led to several problems during the development cycle.

---

This doesn't mean that the use of something is necessarily *wrong*, simply that it's being used in a way that it wasn't intended to be used. Something can even be misused and, in some situations, actually be appropriate and effective.

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence provided as example, "[**abused**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abuse)" is the best option.

> **abuse** (verb) = to use something for the wrong purpose in a way that is harmful or morally wrong:
>
> - She is continually abusing her position/authority by getting other people to do things for her.
> - I never expected that he would abuse the trust I placed in him.
>     to abuse alcohol

And the sentence becomes:

> The Frostbite engine was used to make a RPG, because it was **abused** it led to several problems during the development cycle.

However, this implies something that should be (normally) done.

---

In some cases, the use of the "not optimal tool" is actually the better thing to do, when you have nothing better at hand:

> He did not have a hammer, so he **worked** it **around** using a dictionary.

based on the word "workaround":

> [**workaround**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/workaround) (noun) = a way of dealing with a problem or making something work despite the problem, without completely solving it:
>
> - The software still has a few glitches but we've come up with a **workaround**.

---

Of course, the limit between and "abuse" and "workaround" can be quite blurry sometimes, "proven" in the sentence below:

> He did not have a hammer, so he **worked** it **around** by **abusing** a dictionary.